# Host 'n' number of SignalR hubs in ASP.NET (but MEF'd in)

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have an ASP.NET web project where I need to host a number of SignalR hubs that another MVC3 application will talk to.

My main problem is that I don't know until runtime which Hubs I will be hosting as they need to be MEF'd in.  The DLLs containing the exports (of type IXXXHub) will be in the bin directory of the ASP.NET web site.  At the moment there are 3 exportable types - AHub, BHub and CHub but there could be more, e.g. DHub may be implemented later.

I've gone through the SignalR sample showing how to host in an ASP.NET web project so the part I'm confused about is trying to get mine MEF'd in and host one of each of AHub/BHub/CHub.  I've looked at various approaches using Application_Start but couldn't work out how.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the end by just having the [ImportMany] attribute on a List object in the Global.asax class and then having the MEF catalog/container/ComposeParts code in the Application_Start function.