# Map SignalR Hub after using MEF to load plugin

Tags: mef, signalr

I'm trying to have signalR hub as part of a plugin using MEF. But after calling ImportMany on a List<> object and then adding the catalog/container/ComposeParts part in the Application_Start() method of the Global.asax file, all I get is :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'server' of undefined.

I've got no clue if the problem comes from my interface, the plugin, the global.asax file, or the javascript.

The interface:

```
public interface IPlugin
{

}
```

the plugin:

```
[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
[HubName("testHub")]
public class TestHub : Hub, IPlugin
{
    public string Message()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

in the Global.asax file:

```
    [ImportMany(typeof (IPlugin))]
    private IEnumerable<IPlugin> _plugins { get; set; }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"./Plugins"));
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        //log4net
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

and finally the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.connection.hub.url = 'http://127.0.0.1/signalr/';
        var proxy = $.connection.testHub;
        $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] })
                   .done(function () {
                       proxy.invoke('Message').done(function(res) {
                           alert(res);
                       });
                   })
                   .fail(function () { alert("Could not Connect!"); });
    });
```

the only information I've found was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273652/host-n-number-of-signalr-hubs-in-asp-net-but-mefd-in/13458290#13458290) but I could not make it work. everything works fine when I add the reference manually, but when I have a look at "signalr/hubs" after loading the plugin, then there is not reference to my hub's method.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing makes any sense. You can't do anything with Hub instances. You don't own the creation of them and you can't call them from the server so I don't get the point of making them MEF exports. 

Are you looking for DI?

Comment: Let say you have Project1 with Hub1 and project2 with Hub2. when you add the reference to Project1 and Project2 from let say your main MVC project, and then call RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); in the global.asax then you can call all the methods from hub1 and hub 2 in your javascript. I'm trying to find the best way to do that programmatically, i.e. dynamically loading dll including hubs into my main application.

Comment: I'm pretty new with plugin frameworks / DI, so no doubt I might be confusing myself

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'server' of undefined." This seems like a JavaScript error. If that's the case, why not use something like Chrome's "Pause on Uncaught Exceptions" feature to figure out where the error is being thrown from? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-uncaught-exceptions

Comment: I've created a little project on [github](https://github.com/kadaboum/signalrmef) I will add more comments in the code soon.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that SignalR [caches the generated "signalr/hubs" proxy script](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs#L38) the first time it is requested. SignalR provides the cached script in response every subsequent request to "signalr/hubs".

SignalR not only caches the script itself, but it also [caches the collection of Hubs](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.cs#L22) it finds at the start of the process.

You can work around the cached proxy script issue [by simply not using the proxy script](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy), but that still won't enable you to actually connect to Hubs defined in assemblies that are loaded after the process starts.

If you want to be able to connect to such Hubs, you will need to implement your own [IHubDescriptorProvider](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/IHubDescriptorProvider.cs) that is aware of Hubs defined in plugins loaded at runtime.

You can register your provider with SignalR's [DependencyResolver](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/DefaultDependencyResolver.cs#L85) which can be passed into SignalR via the `Resolver` property of the [HubConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubconfiguration%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) object you pass into [MapSignalR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448256%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

That said, it would probably be easier to restart the app pool/server process whenever a plugin is added to the "./Plugins" directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your indications. I've actually found another solution. I was confused because ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider was actually returning the new hub, but I was unable to contact it. I came accross this project: [https://github.com/cjbhaines/SignalRProxyGenerator](https://github.com/cjbhaines/SignalRProxyGenerator) which helped a lot. I'm creating my own hubs.js file, and reference it instead of signalr/hubs. Works good now!